# Display Wordpress Woocommerce category icon on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is an option in `woocommerce-> products -> categories`
to assign image for category.

I want to have icons(would be perfect if only from primary category)
to display under price on a single product page. 
Can't find appropriate code to use for that, can you help me with that?

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Answer (score 2):

That pretty simple actually, because product categories featured image ( if you have set one ) has been stored as terms meta, which could be retrieved by using

```
get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
```

Here is an idea how you can do it. add the below snippet on your `your-theme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`.

```
<?php 

        $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, "product_cat" );
        echo '<ul class="tax_product_cat_list">';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );            
            if( $image ) {
                echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link ( $term ) .'">' . $term->name . ' <img src="' . $image . '" alt="" /></a></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link ( $term ) .'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            }                                               
        }
        echo '</ul>';

?>
```

You might want to update the html structure for your needs.